# x.xxxx is not a valid floating point. Converting between languages/locals

Tags: string, delphi, floating-point

I have a spanish user who is getting an `invalid floating point error` when doing this

```
var
  S : String;
  R : Real;
begin
  S := '3.12345';
  R := StrToFloat(S); //- Exception here.
```

The reason for this is that his location uses `,` for the decimal place!
How can  I safely convert the string above to a float for the user without it bombing out.

Comment: Do you know (that is, at the time the program is run) the national settings used in the string?

Comment: Yes, I do (reason for it being a string is it's an API response).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Roll your own version of StrToFloat

```
function StrToFloat_UK(const AStr: string): Float;
var
  FS: TFormatSettings;
begin
  FS.Create('en-UK');
  Result:= StrToFloat(AStr, FS): 
end;
```

And use this in place of StrToFloat.

Comment: Now I have absolutely no idea what you are doing. `TFormatSettings` is a record, you know that, right?

Comment: From the embarcadero documentation:    1. Declare a variable of type TFormatSettings.
   2. Call TFormatSettings.Create to populate the TFormatSettings variable with locale information.
   3. Pass the TFormatSettings variable as the last parameter of the string formatting routine.

Comment: Well, it doesn't compile for me. And since when do you need to `Free` a record?! Maybe you are using a newer version of Delphi. In Delphi 2009, the code above is nonsense...

Comment: OK, I see now that this record has changed since Delphi 2009. [Delphi 2009](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/SysUtils_TFormatSettings.html), [Delphi XE](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.TFormatSettings) But surely you should not `Free` it even in Delphi XE!

Answer (score 6):

Use the second overload of `StrToFloat` with a `TFormatSettings` that has `DecimalSeparator` set to  `.`.

Comment: I picked the other over yours due to the source code but both much the same. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Wizzard: That's ok. I couldn't figure out how to initialize a `TFormatSettings` anyway. It's been a few years that I've done Object Pascal and never had to deal with this; this answer was mainly the result of a quick web search (and I was fairly sure that every parsing function that is locale-sensitive must have an option to set the locale to use beforehand).

Answer (score 2):

You could use the procedure `val`, it disregards local system settings.

```
var
S : String;
R : Real;
Test: Integer;
begin
  S := '3.12345';
  Val(S, R, Test);
end;
```

Comment: Cool trick. But I hope that Val isn't restricted only to Real-type, and works fine with Double.  Hopefully there are overloads for double?

Comment: Works with doubles and ints also. It is not overloaded per se, it is compiler magic.

Answer (score 1):

If you *know* that the strings use `.` as the decimal separator, then you should do something like

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Application.UpdateFormatSettings := false;
  DecimalSeparator := '.';
end;
```

The line

```
Application.UpdateFormatSettings := false;
```

is very important. The default value of this property is `true`, and in such case, the `DecimalSeparator` variable may be reverted to its default value (e.g. `,`) anytime, for instance when you switch user.

Comment: Avoid using the global `DecimalSeparator` for this, as you will not know what other units depend in that (and which will break). It is better to use a local `TFormatSettings` instance.

Comment: -1: Ignoring the user's settings for everything in your application is not the way to go, especially when you can use the overloaded version as reported by Joey and Johan.